# Adding External C++ Libraries To Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have started learning C++ recently and I have a project in mind that requires an external C++ library, however i have no idea how i can add that library in Visual Studio Code so that i can call it like `#include <library/module.h>`

I would really like to be able to do this in a text editor and not an IDE because its gonna be a massive waster to configure the IDE exactly like Visual Studio Code

Comment: I prefer using CMake things to do things like this.

Comment: read the VSC C++ doc and the doc for your used compiler